# WPF Datagrid view header binding

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, header, grid

Actually the issue im facing is slight different than what title says.
I try to sumarize the issue below.

```
Class PersonnelViewModel
{

public SelectedPersonnelItem PersonnelItemViewModel;

}

Class PersonnelItemViewModel
{

}
```

Data Context of the View is **A** whereas the Item source of the data grid is **SelectedPersonnelItem** which is a **B** type property in the class **A**. Now i want to bind the grid column to properties defiend within class **A**. But its not working as the context of the grid is another class (**B**). How can i solve this issue ?

XAML

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="1"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPersonnelItem}"
          Name="PersonnelGrid"
          ItemsSource="{Binding PersonnelGridData}"
          event:DatagridRowDoubleClickHandler.MethodName="EditRecord"
          CanUserAddRows="False">
  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn>
      <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsItemChecked, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></CheckBox>
        </DataTemplate>
      </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name/Company"
                        Binding="{Binding Name}" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Qualification"
                        Binding="{Binding Qualification}" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Arrival"
                        Binding="{Binding ArrivalDate}" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Departure"
                        Binding="{Binding DepartureDate}" />
  </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: can not understand you

Comment: how did you fill your datagird??

Comment: From your XAML, the datacontext of Grid is A and the ItemsSource is PersonnelGridData. The SelectedItem is bound to SelectedPersonnelItem. Can you check your description please

Comment: Data Context of grid is SelectedPersonnelItem which is type of PersonnelItemViewModel.

Comment: If the DataContext of your Grid is SelectedPersonnelItem then it has to be DataContext="{Binding SelectedPersonnelItem}" not SelectedItem. SelectedItem != DataContext http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selecteditem.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I managed to get it working. If I directly bind the property to the column header its not populating the value.

I had to do as following:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}">
    <DataGridTextColumn.Header> 
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding DataContext.MyProp, 
                       RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
                       AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" /> 
    </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

Comment: The problem here is the `<DataGridTextColumn>` is not part of WPF's Visual Tree, so when it is used to generate the UI components it doesn't have access to the whole visual tree like other objects would. By specifying a Template though, it creates an object in the Visual Tree first which can access other objects for binding purposes.

Answer (score 3):

You can access the parents datacontext using

```
Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
    AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=DataContext.ColumnName}"
```

So to add a column showing A's Property do

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Company" Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=DataContext.Company}"/>
```

Comment: I gave something like this, Still its not working.

`Header="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
    AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=PersonnelViewModel.Company}"`