# Custom WPF datagrid header and xml binding

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

I've been trying to figure out how to recreate this "complex" datagrid header, binded to an XML file. I haven't found any examples about how to tackle this problem.

This is an example XML data file (which can have more 'sensors' and more 'Measures'):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ShipData>
  <Draught>
    <Measures>
      <Mdata>M1</Mdata>
      <Mdata>M2</Mdata>
    </Measures>
    <Sensor Name="Sensor1">
      <Measurement>
        <Bis>45</Bis>
        <Man>43</Man>
      </Measurement>
      <Measurement>
        <Bis>44</Bis>
        <Man>46</Man>
      </Measurement>
    </Sensor>
    <Sensor Name="Sensor2">
      <Measurement>
        <Bis>45</Bis>
        <Man>43</Man>
      </Measurement>
      <Measurement>
        <Bis>43</Bis>
        <Man>45</Man>
      </Measurement>
    </Sensor>
  </Draught>
</ShipData>
```

And this is how I would style my datagrid:

[image: datagrid with customized double-lined header]

Since the data can change (more sensors, and more measures), I'll be doing some code behind loading of the datagrid.

Edit:
So the things I'm trying to do is:

1. Create the header (consisting of two lines, the upper line spanning two columns)

   **(solved)** >> Since you can't really span multiple columns for the header, the best way is to create a grid, just above the Datagrid with equal [possible solution](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1e414159-70f6-4be3-9be5-56e4f3278366/wpf-multicolumn-super-header?forum=wpf)

   You could play with:

   ```
   <DataGrid.Columns>
     <DataGridTemplateColumn>
       <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>                                    
         <DataTemplate> ...
   ```

   ... but it get's ugly...at least here. I don't think the HeaderTemplate is used for the things I want to do.
2. Bind the xml data to the grid

   Still figuring out (and how to save changes to the data back to the file)

Preferably via code behind

Comment: did you check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16653005/wpf-datagrid-view-header-binding) thread ?

Comment: What is the actual question here? Any ideas on what?

Comment: @aevitas How to code the header and get the data into the grid

Comment: @AccessDenied I do not think that thread helps me for the moment, I've seen it already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem about the "super" header (see above for example):

> Since you can't really span multiple columns for the header, the best way is to create a grid, just above the Datagrid with equal column sizes (or combined sizes for the super header)

I'm stil struggling with the code behind xmlprovider and xpath (but I'll make a new question to not pollute this question any further)