# Bind DataGridColumns Header to DataContext of the window

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, datagrid

I have a `DataGrid` and want to bind the `Header`-property to a property of my windows `DataContext` but I did not get it working.

Binding can be such a pain as (for me) it is never clear which context `this` has when simply using `Binding`. 
I know that the "Context" in the `Binding={}` is a single element of the `DataGrid`s `ItemsSource`. But what is the "Context" for `Header={Binding ???}`?

I've already tried:

```
Header="{Binding Path=DataContext.MyProperty, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}
Header="{Binding Path=DataContext.MyProperty, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}
Header="{Binding Path=DataContext.MyProperty, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type MyWindow}}}
Header="{Binding Path=DataContext.MyProperty, ElementName=MyWindowName}
```

I tried with and without Path but nothing is working.

For example, using the last one with `ElementName` I get the following binding-exception:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 2 : Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for target element. BindingExpression:Path=DataContext.MyProperty; DataItem=null; target element is 'DataGridTextColumn' (HashCode=51072575); target property is 'Header' (type 'Object')
```

Is there any tool to check/change bindings at runtime? Or even to know what the current "Context" is?

Note: The `DataGrid` is inside a Mahapps.Flyout (not sure if this has something to say).

Comment: I use [Snoop](https://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) to look at my DataContext and binding errors at runtime

Answer (score 3):

Since `DataGridTextColumn` or any other supported data grid columns are not part of visual tree of `datagrid` so they don't inherit the `DataContext` of `datagrid`. Since, they don't lie in visual tree so any try to get `DataContext` using `RelativeSource` won't work.

Solution - You can create a proxy element to bind the data context of `window/control`; use that proxy element to bind the Header of `DataGridTextColumn`.

```
<Grid>
   <Grid.Resources>
       <FrameworkElement x:Key="ProxyElement" DataContext="{Binding}"/>
   </Grid.Resources>
       <ContentControl Visibility="Collapsed" Content="{StaticResource ProxyElement}"></ContentControl>
       <DataGrid  
                       ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}" 
                       AutoGenerateColumns="False">
          <DataGrid.Columns>
              <DataGridTextColumn Header="{Binding DataContext.MyProperty, Source={StaticResource ProxyElement}}" Binding="{Binding PropertyName}" />
          </DataGrid.Columns>
     </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks. That's one reason why I'll never like `Bindings`. One the other hand, why is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16653005/wpf-datagrid-view-header-binding) working?

Comment: The ProxyElement is a FrameworkElement that steals the DataContext from the main View and offers it to the logical child such as DataGridTextColumn. For that it must be hosted as a Content into an invisible ContentControl which is under the same View.

Comment: Not sure the answer mentioned in [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16653005/wpf-datagrid-view-header-binding) was ever working.

Comment: Indeed it is working and (for me) it's simpler (and better readable) than using the proxy. But that's just my opinion.