# It's possible to convert event triggers to viewmodel using converters?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

I'm writing WPF app in MVVM using MVVM Light. I have an event trigger in DataGrid to detecting the cell editing ends.

In viewmodel I have command which needs a DataGrid binding item as param. I did it using casting DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs.EditingElement.DataContext to my model. It's work as I want but it's hard to VM testing.

Here's View's trigger

```
// xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
<DataGrid x:Name="PeopleDataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding People}" >
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
                            <i:EventTrigger EventName="CellEditEnding">
                                <cmd:EventToCommand PassEventArgsToCommand="True" Command="{Binding EditPersonRowCommand}"/>
                            </i:EventTrigger>
                        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

And in VM here's the command

```
public RelayCommand<DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs> EditPersonRowCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return editPersonRowCommand ??
                       (editPersonRowCommand =
                           new RelayCommand<DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs>(param => this.EditPersonRow(param.EditingElement.DataContext as PersonForListDto), this.editPersonRowCommandCanExecute));
            }
        }
```

It's possible to using IValueConverter or something to have model right way without control casting?

Comment: Instead of passing data through `PassEventArgsToCommand="True"`, you can do the bind the `CommandParameter` to row's DataContext. With that you don't need to any type casting in VM.

Comment: Did you try `<cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding EditPersonRowCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `PassEventArgsToCommand` dependency property pass the event argument to command. Instead of using `PassEventArgsToCommand`, you can define the binding for `CommandParameter` to pass the DataContext. With this, at VM, the `RelayCommand` can define with actual type. The code at View and ViewModel will be as follows:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
                            <i:EventTrigger EventName="CellEditEnding">
                                <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding EditPersonRowCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding //Since you have not given the full code so not sure how Binding is cascading so if you require to use ReleativeSource to bind to DataContext then use that.}"/>
                            </i:EventTrigger>
                        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

And

```
public RelayCommand<PersonForListDto> EditPersonRowCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return editPersonRowCommand ??
                       (editPersonRowCommand =
                           new RelayCommand<PersonForListDto>(param => this.EditPersonRow(param), this.editPersonRowCommandCanExecute));
            }
        }
```

With above, your VM would be cleaner and can easily be unit tested.

Comment: My Datagrid is binding to ObservableCollection<PersonForListDto>

Comment: Then use `RelativeSource` to find the `DataGrid`'s `DataContext` to bind with `CommandParameter`.

Comment: Something like this? 
CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}, Path=Item}"
I have null parameter in my command calling function.

Comment: You need to create a Proxy element to pass the DataContext inside the template’s item. You can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34067554/bind-datagridcolumns-header-to-datacontext-of-the-window) article.

Comment: it was a bit difficult but yes