# How to bind Header of DataGridTextColumn?

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, datacontext

I'm trying to bind header of a table to property in my ViewModel.

```
<Window x:Class="MyProject.Views.Dialogs.ItemsDialog"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyProject"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Height="300" Width="600" MinWidth="200" MinHeight="200">
<Window.Resources>
    <local:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator" />
</Window.Resources>
<Window.DataContext>
    <Binding Source="{StaticResource Locator}" Path="ItemsDialogModel" />
</Window.DataContext>
<Window.Title>
    <Binding Path="Strings.ItemsDialogTitle" />
</Window.Title>
<Grid Margin="10">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>


            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}" Header="{Binding Strings.ItemNameHeader}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}" Header="{Binding Path=DataContext.Strings.ItemNameHeader, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" />


     // ...
     </DataGrid>

     <TextBlock Text="{Binding Strings.ItemsNameHeader}" Grid.Row="2" />

</Grid>
</Window>
```

Window title binding and other bindings outside `DataGrid` work fine. Data in grid binds successfully too. For example, `TextBlock` under `DataGrid` works without any problems. But both ways of header binding in the code above don't work.

How can I bind header of `DataGridTextColumn` to `Strings.ItemNameHeader` property of view model? Should I use RelativeSource or not?

Comment: I'm trying right now. All google link give `RelativeSource` answer. But It doesn't work, as I mentioned. I tried to use RelativeSource in TextBlock and `x:Type Window` don't work and `x:Type Grid` works! Unfortunately, it don't inside `DataGrid`...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658397/wpf-datagrid-header-text-binding

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16653005/wpf-datagrid-view-header-binding

Comment: if these links gives answer to your Q just mark Q as duplicate. If not - let me know.

Comment: Thaks a lot. Didn't thought this is specifically header problem and was googling "accees to window datacontext" and etc... )

Comment: glad to help. Just a note. If you have any Q about WPF you can ask about it in the [WPF chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18165/wpf) or if you prefer use you native language [C# chat room on Ru-SO](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26962/c-net--)